# How can you play the same songs as a radio station at a higher quality?

Tags: audio

There's an FM radio station I listen to very often, and I really like the way they mix the songs. Much better than simply shuffling my music. I happen to have the vast majority of the songs they play, all properly tagged mp3's @ 320kbps. I would like to have an automated function that tunes in to the radio station, uses a music tagging service such as shazam to find the currently playing song, and plays the higher quality version that I have in its place. Any ideas?

P.S. I'm not sure if this is the right stackexchange community for this question. If not, please redirect me to the proper community.

Comment: Interesting idea! You might be able to use the Radio Data System, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System, which some stations use to identify the current selection. If you write the application, be sure to publish it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That's a good idea, but the station only uses Radio Data System  to broadcast the station's call sign, but not the song title.

Comment: Does the station have a now playing section on their website? Maybe you could scrape that data and have your custom station offset by a few minutes to account for adverts and announcer time.

Comment: No, they don't have that either. I think I would have to use some kind of music identification software, like shazam. I might be able to find an open source program instead of shazam, too.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser, and thank you for your good question! +1. Have you phoned the station and asked them to add a "now playing" section to their website?

Comment: No, I haven't. But I will consider doing so. I was thinking about calling and asking them to update their outdated  radio hosts list anyway. Might as well kill two birds with one stone.

Comment: you could write a applet which analyzes the output of the radio station with a neural network, and identify what they are playing... neural networks are not that hard to program but first, you have to guide the applet, like any good spam filter

Comment: Does the station have a RSS or other feed already setup?  Some have a daily playlist that can be downloaded or emailed to you if you subscribe.

Comment: Why not just play your superior downloads of vast quantities on your Hi-Fidelity system with your mp3 player? This guy might do it for you for about 10 bucks: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-u63sPbjAo

Answer (score 1):

You can install the windows or mac client of shazamo and track the songs.
Or use Stream-That-Song by Orange Innovation, which writes the songs into a spotify playlist where you can play them or export.

Also check https://www.acrcloud.com/music-recognition .
The provide a python/C/java library for music recognition.